Pivot according to similar values
I have an Input:
[
  {
    "Version Name": "CurrentWorkingView",
    "Item": "190001",
    "Location Plant": "A1",
    "Week": "22-Jul-24",
    "Supplier Location": "S920001",
    "DemandCategoryCode": "Standard Demand",
    "ForecastQuantity": 124,
    "ForecastRefreshTimeStamp": null,
    "MaterialDemandID": null,
    "MaterialGlobalAssetID": null,
    "Unit Of Measure": null
  },
  {
    "Version Name": "CurrentWorkingView",
    "Item": "190001",
    "Location Plant": "A1",
    "Week": "22-Jul-24",
    "Supplier Location": "S920001",
    "DemandCategoryCode": "Extraordinary Demand",
    "ForecastQuantity": 97,
    "ForecastRefreshTimeStamp": null,
    "MaterialDemandID": null,
    "MaterialGlobalAssetID": null,
    "Unit Of Measure": null
  },
  {
    "Version Name": "CurrentWorkingView",
    "Item": "190005",
    "Location Plant": "B1",
    "Week": "22-Jul-24",
    "Supplier Location": "S920003",
    "DemandCategoryCode": "Standard Demand",
    "ForecastQuantity": 248,
    "ForecastRefreshTimeStamp": null,
    "MaterialDemandID": null,
    "MaterialGlobalAssetID": null,
    "Unit Of Measure": null
  }
]

My Output is:
{
  "WeekBasedCapacity": [
    {
      "unitOfMeasureIsOmitted": null,
      "materialGlobalAssetId": null,
      "materialDemandId": null,
      "changedAt": null,
      "materialNumberCustomer": "190001",
      "customer": "A1",
      "demandSeries": [
        {
          "expectedSupplierLocation": "S920001",
          "demandCategory": {
            "demandCategoryCode": "Standard Demand"
          },
          "demands": [
            {
              "demand": 124,
              "pointInTime": "22-Jul-24"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "expectedSupplierLocation": "S920001",
          "demandCategory": {
            "demandCategoryCode": "Extraordinary Demand"
          },
          "demands": [
            {
              "demand": 97,
              "pointInTime": "22-Jul-24"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "unitOfMeasureIsOmitted": null,
      "materialGlobalAssetId": null,
      "materialDemandId": null,
      "changedAt": null,
      "materialNumberCustomer": "190005",
      "customer": "B1",
      "demandSeries": [
        {
          "expectedSupplierLocation": "S920003",
          "demandCategory": {
            "demandCategoryCode": "Standard Demand"
          },
          "demands": [
            {
              "demand": 248,
              "pointInTime": "22-Jul-24"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

My Jolt Spec:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Item": {
          "*": {
            "@2": "&[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "0": {
          "Unit Of Measure": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].unitOfMeasureIsOmitted",
          "unitOfMeasureIsOmitted": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].unitOfMeasure",
          "materialDescriptionCustomer": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].materialDescriptionCustomer",
          "MaterialGlobalAssetID": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].materialGlobalAssetId",
          "MaterialDemandID": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].materialDemandId",
          "materialNumberSupplier": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].materialNumberSupplier",
          "supplier": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].supplier",
          "ForecastRefreshTimeStamp": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].changedAt",
          "IsInactive": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].IsInactive",
          "Item": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].materialNumberCustomer",
          "Location Plant": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].customer",
          "Supplier Location": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[0].expectedSupplierLocation",
          "Location": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[0].customerLocation",
          "DemandCategoryCode": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[0].demandCategory.demandCategoryCode",
          "ForecastQuantity": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[0].demands[0].demand",
          "Week": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[0].demands[0].pointInTime"
        },
        "*": {
          "Supplier Location": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[&1].expectedSupplierLocation",
          "Location": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[&1].customerLocation",
          "DemandCategoryCode": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[&1].demandCategory.demandCategoryCode",
          "ForecastQuantity": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[&1].demands[0].demand",
          "Week": "WeekBasedCapacity[#3].demandSeries[&1].demands[0].pointInTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Expected output:
{
  "WeekBasedCapacity": [
    {
      "unitOfMeasureIsOmitted": null,
      "materialGlobalAssetId": null,
      "materialDemandId": null,
      "changedAt": null,
      "materialNumberCustomer": "190001",
      "customer": "A1",
      "demandSeries": [
        {
          "expectedSupplierLocation": "S920001",
          "demandCategory": {
            "demandCategoryCode": "Standard Demand"
          },
          "demands": [
            {
              "demand": 124,
              "pointInTime": "22-Jul-24"
            },
            {
              "demand": 97,
              "pointInTime": "22-Jul-24"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "unitOfMeasureIsOmitted": null,
      "materialGlobalAssetId": null,
      "materialDemandId": null,
      "changedAt": null,
      "materialNumberCustomer": "190005",
      "customer": "B1",
      "demandSeries": [
        {
          "expectedSupplierLocation": "S920003",
          "demandCategory": {
            "demandCategoryCode": "Standard Demand"
          },
          "demands": [
            {
              "demand": 248,
              "pointInTime": "22-Jul-24"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Can you please help in fixing this?

Hi Rahul this spec will help you resolve the query.
I have update the spec you were using.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Item": {
          "*": {
            "@2": "&[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Unit Of Measure": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].unitOfMeasureIsOmitted",
          "unitOfMeasureIsOmitted": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].unitOfMeasure",
          "materialDescriptionCustomer": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].materialDescriptionCustomer",
          "MaterialGlobalAssetID": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].materialGlobalAssetId",
          "MaterialDemandID": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].materialDemandId",
          "materialNumberSupplier": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].materialNumberSupplier",
          "supplier": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].supplier",
          "ForecastRefreshTimeStamp": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].changedAt",
          "IsInactive": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].IsInactive",
          "Item": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].materialNumberCustomer",
          "Location Plant": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].customer",
          "Supplier Location": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].expectedSupplierLocation",
          "DemandCategoryCode": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].demandCategory.demandCategoryCode",
          "ForecastQuantity": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].demands.demand",
          "Week": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#3].demands.pointInTime"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "WeekBasedCapacity": {
        "*": {
          "unitOfMeasureIsOmitted": "ONE",
          "materialGlobalAssetId": "ONE",
          "materialDemandId": "ONE",
          "changedAt": "ONE",
          "materialNumberCustomer": "ONE",
          "customer": "ONE",
          "expectedSupplierLocation": "ONE",
          "demandCategory": {
            "demandCategoryCode": "ONE"
          },
          "demands": "MANY"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "WeekBasedCapacity": {
        "*": {
          "demands": {
            "*": {
              "*": "MANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "WeekBasedCapacity": {
        "*": {
          "*": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#2].&",
          "expectedSupplierLocation": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#2].demandSeries.[#3].expectedSupplierLocation",
          "demandCategory": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#2].demandSeries.[#3].demandCategory",
          "demands": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#2].demandSeries.[#3].demands"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "WeekBasedCapacity": {
        "*": {
          "*": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#2].&",
          "demandSeries": {
            "*": {
              "*": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#4].demandSeries.[#2].&",
              "demands": {
                "*": {
                  "pointInTime": {
                    "*": {
                      "@": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#8].demandSeries.[#6].demands.[#2].pointInTime"
                    }
                  },
                  "demand": {
                    "*": {
                      "@": "WeekBasedCapacity.[#8].demandSeries.[#6].demands.[#2].demand"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Hope this help you resolve the query and if it does then pls upvote and accept the answer.
